# How do I find the library System.Numerics in the ADD reference?

Tags: c#

I need to be able to use BigInteger and Numerics but I cannot find the using System.Numerics reference in the .NET reference list.

**Question: Where is the System.Numerics reference located?**

(I know how to get to the area were you can add in reference)

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Numerics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BigInteger b1 = new BigInteger();
            Complex c1   = new Complex(0, 1);

            Console.WriteLine(b1);
            Console.WriteLine(c1);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Actually it looked like I was not targeting the .NET 3.0 framework.

Comment: what version of .NET Framework you are using?

Comment: `System.Numerics` requires .Net 4.0 or later so you need to target that version or higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add in the using System.Numberics to your project and then it should compile and run.

1. Right click on Reference (Select Add Reference)
2. .NET select
3. Scroll down and select System.Numeric

Note: They say they are in alphabetical order and they sort of but I also have FSharp.Core for example after the M's and so forth. So it is sort of by alphabet but not completely either.

[image]
Make sure you are targeting the .NET 4.0 system. I am somewhat new to Visual Studio but I do not think that these were available in other versions. i don't use these all that much.

Answer (score 3):

They're in alphabetical order...

[image]

Make sure you are targeting .NET 4.0 or above, note.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2010, try this:

in your project,

1. right click in Add new reference,
2. Select `.NET`
3. AND found this reference

Comment: .NET 3 eh? System.Numberics is a .NET 4.0+ assembly: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @tnw I made that mistake too... I think he means "2: Select .NET", and separately "3: AND found this reference"

Comment: @MarcGravell OHH yup. My mistake. Edited his post

Comment: from the question: "I know how to get to the area were you can add in reference"

Answer (score 1):

So long as you know a particular member of the namespace, MSDN actually does a decent job of telling you.  According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on BigInteger: Assembly:  System.Numerics (in System.Numerics.dll)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, OP already knows that assembly is necessary.

Comment: The question was stated as to where is the namespace, which does not have to be the same as the assembly.  Perhaps I misread